# Netlogo operations on list of lists for example [ [100 0] [50 1] [30 2] ]

Tags: netlogo, nested-lists

I am learning to program in NetLogo but I do not understand the following:

If we have a list of lists, how can I return the list with both the lowest item in the 0 index and the highest item in the 1 index?

For example, from:

```
[ [100 0] [50 1] [30 2] ]
```

It must be returned:

```
[30 2]
```

Comment: What would be your desired behavior with a list like `[ [100 3] [50 1] [30 2] ]`?

Comment: thanks for answering me so fast. but I think I've already got it. What I wanted to get from [ [100 3] [50 1] [30 2] ], is the list that has the lowest value of the 0 position and the highest value of the position 1. In this case, [30 2] because 30 is the lowest value in the 0 position  and 2 is the greater value in the position 1

Comment: Glad you sorted it out! I'm just wondering what you do when those items are not in the same list item. For my example, `item 2` (`[30 2]`)  has the lowest value in index 0, but `item 0` (`[100 3]`) has the highest value in index 1. However, if your answer is to your satisfaction please click the little check mark next to it so that this question can be marked as answered.

Comment: yes, in this case I was wrong. The answer is [100 3]. I can´t click the check mark until 2 days because is my own answer

Comment: Ah, gotcha- didn't know that, sorry. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort-by [ [i j] -> ( (item 1 i) > (item 1 j) and (item 0 i) < (item 0 j) ) ] mylist
```